# Collection View to Detail View

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, detailview

I have a collection view of 10 images, and each when pressed is supposed to go to a detail view that displays that image, however I need help pushing the image from the collection view to the detail view. The code I have that grabs all the images is this:

```
    -(MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"test"];


    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.CollectionImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        }
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

And here is the code for the selection of the image:

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TableDetailViewController  *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:objDetail];
    objDetail.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:objDetail.view];
}
```

And I am not even sure what to write in the view did load on the TableDetailViewController. If someone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you want to addChildViewController: and addSubview:.  More common patterns for this are to use presentViewController: if you want a modal detail view, or have a navigationController and use [[self navigationController] pushViewController:...] if you want a back button and all that.